# vim buffer Trying char-by-char conversion

Tags: vim

It could be a windows saved file opened in unix/linux problem and I am not quite sure how to solve it.

When I open a file which was previously saved by another developer using windows, my vim buffer some times shows

```
Trying char-by-char conversion...
```

In the middle of my file and I am unable to edit the code/text/characters right below this message in my buffer.

Why does it do that and how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Convince the Windows users that they should be using Unix :-) Just kidding. Can you show the output of `:set viewoptions?`?

Comment: Haha. I agree. :-D
output is `viewoptions=folds,options,cursor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message comes from the Vim function `mac_string_convert()` in `src/os_mac_conv.c`. It is accompanied by the following comment:

> conversion failed for the whole string, but maybe it will work for each character

Seems like the file you're editing contains a byte sequence that cannot be converted to Vim's internal encoding. It's hard to offer help without more details, but often, these help:

1. Ensure that you have `:set encoding=utf-8`
2. Check `:set filencodings?` and ensure that the file you're trying to open is covered, or explicitly specify an encoding with `:edit ++enc=... file`
3. The `8g8` command can find an illegal UTF-8 sequence, so that you can remove it, in case the file is corrupted. Binary mode `:set binary` / `:edit ++bin` may also help.