# vim NERDTree buffer - Trying char~by-char conversion

Tags: vim, nerdtree

In a previous post here - [vim buffer Trying char-by-char conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454901/vim-buffer-trying-char-by-char-conversion) - I was running into a problem when opening up certain files and vim wasn't able to detect the encodings in that file and this was resolved by the solution provided by Ingo.

But after I installed vim's NERDTree plugin, I am running into the same problem again.

It appears that buffer opened by NERDTree mapping `map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` does not obey the `:set encoding=utf-8` directive.

I have to manually run `:set encoding=utf-8` **again** in order for the `Trying char~by-char conversion...` problem to be resolved.

Also, my nerdtree directory shows up with a weird `?` instead of the `|` symbol. Like this:-
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have temporarily solved this problem by mapping

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>:set encoding=utf-8<CR>
```

instead of the original plain

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

However this solution is not good enough as the `Trying char~by-char conversion` warning still pops up whenever I browse open a specific directory in the NERDTree buffer.

So, I would like to hear if anyone has a better solution! Thanks!

The nerdtree `?` character problem was solved by this post - [vim - nerdtree suddenly broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927217/vim-nerdtree-suddenly-broke)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do anything: NERDTree doesn't manipulate `encoding` and `encoding` is a global option that you set once and for all in your `~/.vimrc`. Go back to an almost empty `~/.vimrc` and build from that (with `encoding` and other options).